# Remove redundancy for types that have the same shape

Tags: typescript

I've created a contrived example ([Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20X%20%3D%20%7B%20foo%3A%20string%3B%20bar%3F%3A%20undefined%3B%20baz%3F%3A%20undefined%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20Y%20%3D%20%7B%20foo%3F%3A%20undefined%3B%20bar%3A%20string%3B%20baz%3F%3A%20undefined%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20Z%20%3D%20%7B%20foo%3F%3A%20undefined%3B%20bar%3F%3A%20undefined%3B%20baz%3A%20string%3B%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20XYZ%20%3D%20X%20%7C%20Y%20%7C%20Z%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20foo(xyz%3A%20XYZ)%3A%20string%20%7C%20undefined%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20xyz.foo%3B%0D%0A%7D)) to try to illustrate my problem. `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` are mutually exclusive. I'm only looking for a solution that keeps `XYZ` as the type for the parameter of my function. I already understand that the type `X` would work here.

```js
type X = { foo: string; bar?: undefined; baz?: undefined }
type Y = { foo?: undefined; bar: string; baz?: undefined }
type Z = { foo?: undefined; bar?: undefined; baz: string; }
type XYZ = X | Y | Z;

function foo(xyz: XYZ): string | undefined {
    return xyz.foo;
}
```

Ideally I would only have to define the required parts:

```js
type X = { foo: string };
type Y = { bar: string };
type Z = { baz: string };
```

But without the redundancy, I get this error message:

```
Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'XYZ'.
  Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Y'.
```

I've tried this, but I end up with types that look like `undefined & string`:

```
type XYZ = { foo?: undefined; bar?: undefined; baz?: undefined } & (X | Y | Z);
```

Comment: If it has `foo`, are you saying that `bar` **must** be `undefined`? I don't think you can do that with a single type, but I'm not Titian Cernicova-Dragomir, so...

Comment: At the very least, the current type prevents you from creating an object that has both `foo` and `bar`. I'm not sure I'll be able to type narrow within the function body.

Comment: *"I'm not sure I'll be able to type narrow within the function body."* There has to be some way (even if it's a property check as in my answer), otherwise how do you write the function's logic?

Comment: In this example it looks like the shape of `XYZ` is `{ foo: string, bar: string, baz: string }` so I just haven't had the type safety I thought I did.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for `&` (an [intersection type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types)), rather than `|` (a [union type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types)):

```
type X = { foo: string };
type Y = { bar: string };
type Z = { baz: string };
type XYZ = X & Y & Z;
```

From the intersection types documentation:

> An intersection type combines multiple types into one. This allows you to add together existing types to get a single type that has all the features you need. For example, `Person & Serializable & Loggable` is a `Person` and `Serializable` and `Loggable`. That means an object of this type will have all members of all three types.

[Working on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20X%20%3D%20%7B%20foo%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20Y%20%3D%20%7B%20bar%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20Z%20%3D%20%7B%20baz%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20XYZ%20%3D%20X%20%26%20Y%20%26%20Z%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20foo(xyz%3A%20XYZ)%3A%20string%20%7C%20undefined%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20xyz.foo%3B%0D%0A%7D).

---

That said, if you're saying that when `foo` exists, `bar` and `baz` **must** be undefined, I think you'd stick with an intersection type, but then you have to tell TypeScript that you know `foo` exists before you use it by doing a [type assertion](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions). Because otherwise, it can't know that you're dealing with an `X` and not a `Y` or `Z`. E.g.:

```
type X = { foo: string };
type Y = { bar: string };
type Z = { baz: string };
type XYZ = X | Y | Z;

function foo(xyz: XYZ): string | undefined {
    if ("foo" in xyz) { // Or whatever appropriate check
        return (xyz as X).foo;
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20X%20%3D%20%7B%20foo%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20Y%20%3D%20%7B%20bar%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20Z%20%3D%20%7B%20baz%3A%20string%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20XYZ%20%3D%20X%20%7C%20Y%20%7C%20Z%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20foo(xyz%3A%20XYZ)%3A%20string%20%7C%20undefined%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(%22foo%22%20in%20xyz)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(xyz%20as%20X).foo%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%7D).

I don't think there's a way to do it without the type assertion. (But again, I'm not Titian Cernicova-Dragomir. :-) )

---

Another option is to use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads), but you've said specifically you want to keep `XYZ` and it would still require that you have logic to detect what you're dealing with, with type assertions.

Comment: I was hoping to keep `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` mutually exclusive. I just realized that even in my example, `if (xyz.foo)` does not narrow `xyz.bar` to `undefined`.

Comment: @Wex - Heh, I just realized that might be what you were looking for and was updating. :-)